# UICollectionView Different cells widths

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

Hi, I would like to make a design like this, I have a collectionView that has different sections, the first one has to be different... how can I do?

I have made different types of cells but it always has the same width as specified in the storyboard... Is there any way to set the width of the cell?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to adopt the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol and implement the `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)` method.  This method is implemented to specify the size of individual items to the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` object that does the layout in a collection view by default.

Here is a link to [the relevant documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:).

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, specifically this method:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Just return there the size you want at the section or indexPath you need.